# Issue when trying resize a Uiimage

Tags: swift, png, webp

I have a Uiimage (usually with transparency) and I need to make it 512x512 and at most 100kb.
I was able to resize to 512x512 (but the images were around 400kb), however and when I use the jpegData (compressionQuality: 0.3) method I lose the transparency of the image.

```
let imagePNG = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3)
try stickerPack.addSticker(imageData: imagePNG!, type: ImageDataExtension(rawValue: "png")!, emojis: [""])
```

Is there any way to reduce the size of the image without losing transparency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I have this problem before when creating WhatsApp Sticker Packs)

If it is possible, you can try Google's [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) format. It is a file format to minimize the image size and not to lose the transparency. You can try the [libwebp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/api) official library to compress and encode your image, but I recommend you to use [YYImage](https://github.com/ibireme/YYImage). After [installing YYImage](https://github.com/ibireme/YYImage#installation), use `YYCGImageCreateEncodedWebPData()` to create and compress your CGImage (`UIImage.cgImage?`) to WebP data (more accurately, `Unmanged<CFData>`).

Hope this help.

Comment: I did as you said I imported the library, converted the image using the YYCGImageCreateEncodedWebPData method and I'm not able to add in the stickerPack.addSticker () method.

"Cannot convert value of type 'Unmanaged<CFData>?' to expected argument type 'Data'". Some help on how to handle this? Thanks!

Comment: You can convert `Unmanaged<CFData>` to `Data` using `unmanagedData.takeUnretainedValue() as Data`.

Comment: It worked! The image of 400kb was around 150kb.
I still need to shrink a bit more. But your answer already helped me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
extension UIImage {
    enum JPEGQuality: CGFloat {
        case lowest  = 0
        case low     = 0.25
        case medium  = 0.5
        case high    = 0.75
        case highest = 1
    }

    func jpeg(_ quality: JPEGQuality) -> Data? {
        return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, quality.rawValue)
    }
}
```